# Display manytomany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a problem with manytomany relationship. I have two entities, campaign (which is the owning side) and user (which extends FOSUserBundle).

This is a bidirectionnal ManyToMany relationship, and when I create a new campaign, I have an entry added to a table named  *users_campaigns*.

My problem is that on the profile page of the user, I would like to display all the campaigns he is related with.

I overrided the FOSUB twig template with this :

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<div class="panel panel-default">

<div class="panel-heading">
    {{ 'profile.show.username'|trans }}
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    {{ user.username }}
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    {{ 'profile.show.email'|trans }}
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    {{ user.email }}
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    {{ 'profile.show.lastlogin'|trans }}
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    {{ user.lastlogin|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
    {{ 'profile.show.campaigns'|trans }}
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    {% if user.campaigns is defined %}
        {%  for campaign in user.campaigns %}
            {{ campaign.name }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

I also overrided the ProfileController, and tried some things there, but I did not manage to display the campaigns.

Does anyone have any idea ?

EDIT : The relations :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="campaigns" , cascade={"all"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_campaigns")
 */
private $players;
```

and :

```
    /**
 * ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Campaign", mappedBy="players", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $campaigns;
```

EDIT 2 :
Here are the construct from the user class.

```
    public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->campaigns = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

And here is the getter for the campaign :

```
    /**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getCampaigns()
{
    return $this->campaigns;
}
```

Comment: show us the relations you've created

Comment: FOSUserBundle is just a convinience, you need to make use of Doctrine Entities and set mappings on them.

Comment: I edited the post and added the relations. As you can see, I use entities and made a relationship between both of them.

Comment: Can you show us how looks your `__construct` and getter for `campaigns` in `Player` entity?

Comment: I edited the post with the informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so stupid...

After looking again and again at my code, I saw that the annotations for campaigns in the User class where missing @ at the beggining of the line.

I wrote

```
ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Campaign", mappedBy="players", cascade={"all"})
```

instead of

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Campaign", mappedBy="players", cascade={"all"})
```

Apologize to everyone, and thank you for trying to help me.